# PHP MySQL get position of record in ordered recordset

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking at how I can get the position of a record in an ordered SQL recordset

It's an online leaderboard, I've set the id of the last submitted score to $myID, so now I need to get what ranking it got.

I'll be ordering them like so;

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboards ORDER BY score DESC
```

What do I add to the statement to just get a specific position of an id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give the desired result

```
SELECT count(id) FROM leaderboards where score >= (
    select score from leaderbords where id = $myID
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most common approach is:

```sql
SET @rowcount = 0;
SELECT lb.*, (@rowcount := @rowcount + 1) as 'position' 
  FROM leaderboards lb ORDER BY score DESC
```

and whole query would look like

```sql
SET @rowcount = 0;
SELECT rc.position 
  FROM (
    SELECT lb.id, (@rowcount := @rowcount + 1) as 'position' 
      FROM leaderboards lb ORDER BY score DESC
  ) rc
  WHERE rc.id = $myID
```

Comment: of course in the subquery you don't need to fetch all fields, rather than only id one